# Sylius Grid EntityFilter - sort or use repository

Tags: symfony, sylius

I added a large entity filter to one of my Sylius grid configurations. I haven't found any configuration options besides `class` name and from the looks of it, option values are just ordered by ID. Is there a way to use a repository method or at least provide sort field? Do I need to use a custom filter for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define what repository method to use on your YAML file and what arguments you want to send to that method:

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        app_user: # Your grid name
            driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: "%app.model.user%"
                    repository:
                        method: myCustomMethod
                        arguments:
                            id: resource.id
            sorting:
                name: asc
            limits: [10, 25, 50, 100]
```

Check the Sylius Grid Bundle documentation for more information: [Configuration Reference](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.4/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusGridBundle/configuration.html)

Comment: Sorry but this defines a repository method for the grid itself, main instance. What I wanted is a similar option for a filter definition, i.e. 

           filters: 
                city:
                    type: entity
                    form_options:
                         class: Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\City
#                         repository:
#                            method: getCities

but this doesn't work.

Comment: You will need a Type, the Filter and then tag the service:
`name: sylius.grid_filter, type: my_entity_type, form_type: AppBundle\Grid\Filter\MyEntityFilterType`, then you can use filter: my_entity_type, if that's what you need I'll edit my answer with the working code I have

Comment: @SantiBarbat hey, I know 1 year has gone trough, but I'm needing exactly what you said, could you please share this info? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to define a new type :

```
final class CustomFilterType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add(
        'shop',
        EntityType::class,
        [
            'class' => Shop::class,
            'label' => false,
            'multiple' => true, //if you need multiple selection
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
               return $er->createQueryBuilder('s');
               // define your query builder here
            },
            'choice_label' => function ($shop) { /** @var $shop Shop */
                return $shop->getName();
            },
        ]
    );
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix(): string
{
    return 'sylius_grid_filter_entity_multiple';
}
}
```

Then in your services.yaml :

```
app.grid_filter.custom_filter:
    class: Sylius\Component\Grid\Filter\SelectFilter
    tags: [{
               name: 'sylius.grid_filter',
               type: 'custom_type',
               form_type: App\Form\Grid\Filter\CustomFilterType
           }]
```

And finally, in your grid definition:

```
        filters:
            shops:
                type: custom_type
                label: app.ui.shops
```